# mysqli_num_rows always returning 0 while mysqli_query returns correct values

Tags: php, mysql

I seem to have a little with the mysqli_num_rows function.

My mysql_query is running fine, returning what it should, but once I try to count the rows in what is returned, num_rows keeps returning 0.

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $connect = mysqli_connect( 'localhost', 'root', 'root', 'accounts');

    //check if two passwords are equal to each other
        if ($_POST['pass'] == $_POST['confirm_pass']) {

    //define email variable with submitted values from $_POST
        $email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

    //md5 hash 
        $pass = md5($_POST['pass']);

    //unique user test
        $query = mysqli_query($connect ,'SELECT * FROM users WHERE email="$_email"', MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT);
        $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
        print_r ($numrows) ; die();

        }
    }
?>
```

Thanks a lot for helping me out, this function i

Comment: How do you know the query is returning a row? What does `print_r(mysqli_fetch_assoc($query));` show?

Comment: Refer to this: [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

Comment: Variables are only expanded inside double quotes, you have single quotes around the SQL. But it would be best if you learned to use prepared statements instead of variable substitution.

Comment: @LoganWayne The problem isn't the quotes in his SQL, it's the quotes in his PHP.

Comment: MD5 is not sufficient for passwords.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords with a uselessly weak hash like SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Comment: @Barmar - with his current query, I think the query will be read as `SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=tadman@so.com` where it should be `SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='tadman@so.com'`. But using parametized queries would the better recommendation here.

Comment: Your database connection is in `$connect` but you used `$mysqli` in your `real_escape_string()`. Where did `$mysqli` variable came from?

Comment: @LoganWayne this file is included in another php file where I defined $mysqli as $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "accounts");.

Comment: @LoganWayne With his current query, it will be read as `SELECT * FROM users WHERE email="$_email"`. The single quotes around the PHP string prevent the variable from being expanded. MySQL allows either single or double quotes around strings in the query.

Comment: @Madd0X If you connect in the include file, why do you connect again in this file?